# Cross-origin frame error while trying to get screenshot from iframe

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, cross-domain

I'm trying to get a screenshot from a youtube video with JavaScript. I am able to take it from youtube's website. But when i get the video in my own project with the iframe and try to get screenshot i am getting a cross-origin frame error. Is it possible to get screenshot from iframe?

```
(function(window, document) {
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
    var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

    var iframeImage = new Image();

    iframeImage.onload = function() {
        // Draw image on iframe
        canvas.width = parseInt(iframe.offsetWidth);
        canvas.height = parseInt(iframe.offsetHeight);

        ctx.drawImage(iframeImage, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var base64ImageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        var filename = 'snap-' + canvas.width + 'x' + canvas.height + '-' + Date.now() + '.jpg';

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = filename;
        a.href = base64ImageData;

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = base64ImageData;
        img.alt = filename;
        img.title = 'Click for save: ' + filename;

        window.open().document.body.appendChild(a).appendChild(img);
    };

    // Upload iframe image
    iframeImage.src = iframe.src;

})(window, document);
```

Comment: Not sure where you would be getting an actual screenshot with the shown code (as far as I can tell, it only works for _images_ to begin with?) - but no, I don't think you will be able to get this working for cross-domain content.